# Safari dosen't open anymore "reopen"

Tags: macos, safari, osx-yosemite

I cant open Safari anymore! :(
Every time I try it opens a window with this message instead:

```
Process:               Safari [336]
Path:                  /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
Identifier:            com.apple.Safari
Version:               8.0.2 (10600.2.5)
Build Info:            WebBrowser-7600002005000000~1
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Safari [336]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2014-12-22 22:12:30.768 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        809FBF0B-8B0B-FFEB-6941-625CB5EF21F6


Time Awake Since Boot: 24 seconds

Crashed Thread:        15

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020

External Modification Warnings:
Thread creation by external task.

VM Regions Near 0x20:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000104a41000-0000000104a42000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari

Application Specific Information:
Process Model:
Multiple Web Processes


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e07500e __open_nocancel + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ac7943a _CFIterateDirectory + 74
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8acabf8d _CFBundleReadDirectory + 381
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8acab89a _CFBundleCreateQueryTableAtPath + 602
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8acab583 _CFBundleCopyQueryTable + 179
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8acaae72 _CFBundleCopyURLsOfKey + 354
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8acaa5f1 _CFBundleCopyFindResources + 1153
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8acd7869 CFBundleCopyResourceURLInDirectory + 217
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3b1f2b TISMapAppleKeyLayoutData + 101
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3b1e67 TISGetAppleKeyLayoutIndexForNumericID + 23
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3b1d61 islcGetKeyboardLayoutIndexFromNameAndID + 75
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3b1c58 islcGetInputSourceCacheIndexFromData + 169
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3b0bd0 islGetInputSourceListWithAdditions + 820
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3b087b TSMGetInputSourceCountWithFilteredAdditions + 39
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3afecb TISCreateInputSourceList + 93
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3af92d SyncHandwritingHotKey + 136
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3ae8fd _FirstEventTime + 1086
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3ae385 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 49
18  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3ae0be ReceiveNextEventCommon + 179
19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d3adffb _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b08b6d1 _DPSNextEvent + 964
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b08ae80 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
22  com.apple.Safari.framework      0x0000000104abdad0 -[BrowserApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 246
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b07ee23 -[NSApplication run] + 594
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b06a2d4 NSApplicationMain + 1832
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff91efc5c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e07622e kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e4dba6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e075946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e075946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e075946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e075946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.utility-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e0765d6 pread + 10
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff94f41d75 readDbPage + 117
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff94f4050b sqlite3PagerAcquire + 1307
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff94f83fe2 moveToRoot + 482
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff94f8ef55 sqlite3BtreeMovetoUnpacked + 229
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff94f763fc sqlite3VdbeExec + 42604
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00007fff94f6a457 sqlite3_step + 775
7   com.apple.PubSub                0x00007fff8e8fe813 SQLite::Cursor::nextRow() + 45
8   com.apple.PubSub                0x00007fff8e90205e SQLite::Query::_firstRow() + 26
9   com.apple.PubSub                0x00007fff8e912afd SQLite::QueryOf<PubSub::ClientCore>::firstRow() + 23
10  com.apple.PubSub                0x00007fff8e91175a PubSub::ClientCore::existingClientWithSignature(__CFString const*) + 126
11  com.apple.PubSub                0x00007fff8e911900 PubSub::ClientCore::createClient(__CFString const*) + 256
12  com.apple.PubSub                0x00007fff8e91a67f +[PSClient clientForBundleIdentifier:] + 206
13  com.apple.PubSub                0x00007fff8e91a572 +[PSClient applicationClient] + 78
14  com.apple.Safari.framework      0x0000000104a59fd5 __48-[AppController unsubscribeFromFeedsIfNecessary]_block_invoke + 133
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e4dd323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e4d8c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e4db88f _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 935
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e4e9fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df426cb _pthread_wqthread + 729
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:: WebCore: IconDatabase
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e075132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.WebCore               0x000000010667188b WebCore::IconDatabase::syncThreadMainLoop() + 411
2   com.apple.WebCore               0x000000010666e9d9 WebCore::IconDatabase::iconDatabaseSyncThread() + 361
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x000000010582ca9f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df422fc _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df42279 _pthread_start + 176
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e075946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:: com.apple.CoreAnimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e07052e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e06f69f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8f732d63 CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 198
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8f732c96 thread_fun + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df422fc _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df42279 _pthread_start + 176
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e07052e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e06f69f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8accab14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8acc9fdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8acc9838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff91c47d20 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f1fbb7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df422fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df42279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e075946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e075946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e075946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df404a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:

Thread 15 Crashed:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8df40695 _pthread_mutex_lock + 87
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8db6bb78 vfprintf_l + 28
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8db64620 fprintf + 186
3   ???                             0x000000010c9535dc 0 + 4506072540

Thread 15 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff7a5eb1d8  rcx: 0x00007fff7a5eb1f0  rdx: 0x00000000000000a0
  rdi: 0x00007fff7a5eb1f0  rsi: 0x00007fff8df40b14  rbp: 0x000000010c94fe30  rsp: 0x000000010c94fdb0
   r8: 0x000000010c957000   r9: 0x0000000000000054  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff7a5ea6b8  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff8df40695  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000020

Logical CPU:     5
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x104a41000 -        0x104a41fff  com.apple.Safari (8.0.2 - 10600.2.5) <2225AE13-780E-3234-9A05-9DD6D94EE96C> /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
       0x104a47000 -        0x105380ff7  com.apple.Safari.framework (10600 - 10600.2.5) <70257BE2-5D89-3EAA-8863-269880160EEE> /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Safari
       0x105822000 -        0x105d35ff3  com.apple.JavaScriptCore (10600 - 10600.2.1) <ABEF8FB3-6DC5-3FCF-9B4A-1DF6411063B0> /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore
       0x105ea0000 -        0x106154fff  com.apple.WebKit (10600 - 10600.2.5) <11CA89A1-A002-3FEB-8046-B31E92003AED> /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit
       0x10642c000 -        0x10642cfff  com.apple.WebKit2 (10600 - 10600.2.5) <ED09F7D3-1F46-3925-8E11-D6AC3492658E> /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit2.framework/Versions/A/WebKit2
       0x106438000 -        0x106574ffb  com.apple.WebKitLegacy (10600 - 10600.2.5) <0A88D3D6-F5BA-30F4-9D09-87DF653759FC> /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKitLegacy.framework/Versions/A/WebKitLegacy
       0x10666a000 -        0x10760fff7  com.apple.WebCore (10600 - 10600.2.1) <628CB849-0E8D-3071-98A3-55E7D24087DF> /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore
       0x10b948000 -        0x10b948fe7 +cl_kernels (???) <6F5BDE3C-CCEF-4C3C-A474-053889DA4679> cl_kernels
       0x10c95a000 -        0x10c95afef +cl_kernels (???) <4FDC394E-F26A-4C8F-AD61-8DACED38982D> cl_kernels
       0x10d63c000 -        0x10d722fef  unorm8_bgra.dylib (2.4.5) <90797750-141F-3114-ACD0-A71363968678> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ImageFormats/unorm8_bgra.dylib
    0x7fff61a5a000 -     0x7fff61a90837  dyld (353.2.1) <4696A982-1500-34EC-9777-1EF7A03E2659> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff899c7000 -     0x7fff899dbff7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework (260.30 - 260.30) <28728A7D-E048-3B14-9932-839A87D381FE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
    0x7fff899dc000 -     0x7fff899deff7  libquarantine.dylib (76) <DC041627-2D92-361C-BABF-A869A5C72293> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff89b46000 -     0x7fff89b50ff7  com.apple.NetAuth (5.0 - 5.0) <B9EC5425-D38D-308C-865F-207E0A98BAC7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff89b66000 -     0x7fff89b66fff  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.12 - 1.12) <76EF1C9D-DEA4-3E55-A134-4099B2FD2CF2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff89b67000 -     0x7fff89c0dfff  com.apple.PDFKit (3.0 - 3.0) <C55D8F39-561D-32C7-A701-46F76D6CC151> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PDFKit.framework/Versions/A/PDFKit
    0x7fff8a276000 -     0x7fff8a2d0ff7  com.apple.LanguageModeling (1.0 - 1) <ACA93FE0-A0E3-333E-AE3C-8EB7DE5F362F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
    0x7fff8a5f9000 -     0x7fff8a67aff3  com.apple.CoreUtils (1.0 - 101.1) <45E5E51B-947E-3F2D-BD9C-480E72555C23> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/Versions/A/CoreUtils
    0x7fff8a67b000 -     0x7fff8a67efff  com.apple.IOSurface (97 - 97) <D4B4D2B2-7B16-3174-9EA6-55E0A10B452D> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff8a682000 -     0x7fff8a683ffb  libremovefile.dylib (35) <3485B5F4-6CE8-3C62-8DFD-8736ED6E8531> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff8a684000 -     0x7fff8aa91ff7  libLAPACK.dylib (1128) <F9201AE7-B031-36DB-BCF8-971E994EF7C1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff8aa92000 -     0x7fff8aa94fff  com.apple.OAuth (25 - 25) <EE765AF0-2BB6-3689-9EAA-689BF1F02A0D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/Versions/A/OAuth
    0x7fff8aa95000 -     0x7fff8aa98fff  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <7E9E6BB7-AEE7-3F59-BAC0-59EAF105D0C8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
    0x7fff8aa99000 -     0x7fff8abd3ff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1038) <AB3C40DB-FCBE-3315-B7B2-4E16522E20CB> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff8abd4000 -     0x7fff8ac48ff3  com.apple.securityfoundation (6.0 - 55126) <E7FB7A4E-CB0B-37BA-ADD5-373B2A20A783> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff8ac49000 -     0x7fff8ac54ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (5.2.6 - 5.2.6) <9434AA45-B6BD-37F7-A866-172196A7F91B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff8ac55000 -     0x7fff8ac57ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (358.1.1) <DB9962EF-8898-31CC-9B87-E01F8CE74C9D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff8ac58000 -     0x7fff8afeefff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1151.16) <F2B088AF-A5C6-3FAE-9EB4-7931AF6359E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff8b01e000 -     0x7fff8b038ff7  com.apple.AppleVPAFramework (1.0.30 - 1.0.30) <D47A2125-C72D-3298-B27D-D89EA0D55584> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVPA.framework/Versions/A/AppleVPA
    0x7fff8b039000 -     0x7fff8b03dff7  libGIF.dylib (1231) <B3D2DF96-A67D-31EA-9A1B-E870B54855EE> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff8b04e000 -     0x7fff8b05cfff  libIASAuthReboot.dylib (920) <B165E345-197F-3DC7-A52B-64C34FD95D0A> /usr/lib/libIASAuthReboot.dylib
    0x7fff8b05d000 -     0x7fff8b05ffff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (699.1.5) <9FBA1CE4-97D0-347E-A443-93ED94512E92> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff8b060000 -     0x7fff8b062fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib (11.0.7) <29D775BB-A11D-3140-A478-2A0DA1A87420> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x7fff8b063000 -     0x7fff8b066ff7  com.apple.AppleSystemInfo (3.0 - 3.0) <E54DA0B2-3515-3B1C-A4BD-54A0B02B5612> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSystemInfo.framework/Versions/A/AppleSystemInfo
    0x7fff8b067000 -     0x7fff8bba8fff  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 1343.16) <C98DB43F-4245-3E6E-A4EE-37DAEE33E174> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff8bba9000 -     0x7fff8bbb3fff  com.apple.IntlPreferences (2.0 - 150.1) <F2DE1784-F780-3E3F-A626-D9CBD38F20EE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntlPreferences.framework/Versions/A/IntlPreferences
    0x7fff9859c000 -     0x7fff985a3ff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <BF8FC133-EE10-3DA6-9B90-92039E28678F> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff985bd000 -     0x7fff985bdfff  libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib (162) <EFD79173-A9DA-3AE6-BE15-3948938204A6> /usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib
    0x7fff985be000 -     0x7fff985c1ff7  com.apple.Mangrove (1.0 - 1) <2AF1CAE9-8BF9-33C4-9C1B-123DBAF1522B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Mangrove.framework/Versions/A/Mangrove
    0x7fff985c2000 -     0x7fff98602fff  com.apple.CloudDocs (1.0 - 280.1.2) <49E75BC1-6556-36B4-804A-E49BC41241CF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/Versions/A/CloudDocs
    0x7fff98603000 -     0x7fff98627ff7  com.apple.quartzfilters (1.10.0 - 1.10.0) <1AE50F4A-0098-34E7-B24D-DF7CB94073CE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuartzFilters.framework/Versions/A/QuartzFilters
    0x7fff98628000 -     0x7fff98645ffb  libresolv.9.dylib (57) <26B38E61-298A-3C3A-82C1-3B5E98AD5E29> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff98649000 -     0x7fff98650fff  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0) <1581D25F-CC07-39B0-90E8-5D4F3CF84EBA> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff98651000 -     0x7fff988fdfff  com.apple.GeoServices (1.0 - 982.4.10) <8A7FE04A-2785-30E7-A6E2-DC15D170DAF5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/Versions/A/GeoServices
    0x7fff988fe000 -     0x7fff98959fff  com.apple.QuickLookFramework (5.0 - 675) <D71CD23B-643B-341B-A890-57FE099B36C7> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/QuickLook
    0x7fff9895a000 -     0x7fff98985ff3  libarchive.2.dylib (30) <8CBB4416-EBE9-3574-8ADC-44655D245F39> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
    0x7fff98c7d000 -     0x7fff98c7dfff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (48 - 48) <5BF7910B-C328-3BF8-BA4F-CE52B574CE01> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff98c7e000 -     0x7fff98f65ffb  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1108.1 - 1108.1) <55A16172-ACC0-38B7-8409-3CB92AF33973> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff98f66000 -     0x7fff98f67fff  libSystem.B.dylib (1213) <DA954461-EC6A-3DF0-8551-6FC810627627> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff98f68000 -     0x7fff98fc7ff3  com.apple.AE (681 - 681) <7F544183-A515-31A8-B45F-89A167F56216> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff98fd5000 -     0x7fff98fd7ff7  com.apple.SecCodeWrapper (4.0 - 238) <F450AB10-B0A4-3B55-A1B9-563E55C99333> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SecCodeWrapper.framework/Versions/A/SecCodeWrapper
    0x7fff98fd8000 -     0x7fff98fddfff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.6 - 2.6) <0DFF4D9B-2AC3-3B82-B5C5-30F4EFBD2DB9> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff98fde000 -     0x7fff9900afff  com.apple.framework.SystemAdministration (1.0 - 1.0) <F2A164C7-4813-3F27-ABF7-810A5F4FA51D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Versions/A/SystemAdministration
    0x7fff9900b000 -     0x7fff9905cff7  com.apple.AppleVAFramework (5.0.31 - 5.0.31) <762E9358-A69A-3D63-8282-3B77FBE0147E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVA.framework/Versions/A/AppleVA
    0x7fff99076000 -     0x7fff9909afef  libJPEG.dylib (1231) <3F87A0CA-14FA-3034-A332-DD57A092B08F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff9909b000 -     0x7fff990befff  com.apple.Sharing (328.3 - 328.3) <FDEE49AD-8804-3760-9C14-8D1D10BBEA37> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Sharing.framework/Versions/A/Sharing
    0x7fff9916a000 -     0x7fff991a3fff  com.apple.AirPlaySupport (2.0 - 215.10) <E4159036-4C38-3F28-8AF3-4F074DAF01AC> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/Versions/A/AirPlaySupport
    0x7fff991a4000 -     0x7fff99281ff7  com.apple.QuickLookUIFramework (5.0 - 675) <84FEB409-7D7A-35AC-83BE-F79FB293E23E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/QuickLookUI

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 2
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 178
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=270.9M resident=113.7M(42%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=157.2M(58%)
Writable regions: Total=1.1G written=8064K(1%) resident=11.9M(1%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.1G(99%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
Activity Tracing                     2048K
CG backing stores                     992K
CG image                               24K
CG shared images                      208K
CoreImage                              16K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                       8K
MALLOC                               92.9M
MALLOC (admin)                         32K
OpenCL                                 16K
SQLite page cache                    1792K
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                14.2M
Stack (reserved)                      520K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
VM_ALLOCATE                          17.1M
WebKit Malloc                        1296K
__DATA                               26.4M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                           85.6M
__TEXT                              185.4M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                          59.1M
shared memory                           4K
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                 1.5G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      544.0M


Model: MacBookPro11,2, BootROM MBP112.0138.B11, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.18f15
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.10)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.1f2 15015, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
```

And two buttons:

- Ok(close the Error window)
- Reopen(close the Error window and open it again)

I did this steps:

- Restart
- Clear Safari Preferences
- The Safari Extensions folder is empty(i didnt install any)

Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: See [Safari crash and refusal/failure to reload](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162694/safari-crash-and-refusal-failure-to-reload)

Answer (score 1):

I've just worked on a machine with the same problem. It turned out to be caused by a piece of software called Genieo, see http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-genieo/ . Be aware that that guide seems not completely correct, technically, so think twice before acting on it.