# Please explain what the Error with OS X 10.10.2 and MacWinDjVu (does not open any more) is and how to solve it

Tags: macos, crash, osx-yosemite, djvu

Please explain what the Error with OS X 10.10.2 and MacWinDjVu (does not open any more) is and how to solve it.

I use DjVu regularly, and until today I did not have any problem. I just turned on my MacBook Pro, tried to open a .djvu file and this message appeared:

```
Process:               MacDjView [908]
Path:                  /Applications/MacDjView.app/Contents/MacOS/MacDjView
Identifier:            org.andrew.zhezherun.macdjview
Version:               0.1.2 (0.1.2)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           MacDjView [908]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-02-20 00:30:59.422 -0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C109)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        B091E46F-B552-1FC0-46CB-DD4B2C6CD4F0


Time Awake Since Boot: 2300 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000c0000000

VM Regions Near 0xc0000000:
    Stack                  00000000bffff000-00000000c0000000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
--> 
    Submap                 00000000ffff0000-00000000ffff1000 [    4K] r--/r-- SM=PRV  process-only VM submap

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x96ab51b0 _platform_memmove$VARIANT$sse42 + 192
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x94c39f02 __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 3010
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x94c4e341 CFStringCreateWithCharacters + 97
3   org.andrew.zhezherun.macdjview  0x00003d55 AppSettings::Load() + 889
4   org.andrew.zhezherun.macdjview  0x0000b23f main + 203
5   org.andrew.zhezherun.macdjview  0x000025c6 _start + 228
6   org.andrew.zhezherun.macdjview  0x000024e1 start + 41

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95c5d8ce kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x9c02373f _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 245
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x9c0233a2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95c5ce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9733d2b1 _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9733ae2e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95c5ce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9733d2b1 _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9733ae2e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95c5ce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9733d2b1 _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9733ae2e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95c5ce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9733d2b1 _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9733ae2e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95c5ce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9733d2b1 _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9733ae2e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x0001fdff  ebx: 0xbffff876  ecx: 0x0000003c  edx: 0xfffe0a00
  edi: 0x001d7d90  esi: 0xc001f5fa  ebp: 0xbffff368  esp: 0xbffff360
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010286  eip: 0x96ab51b0   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0xc0000000

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x114feb +org.andrew.zhezherun.macdjview (0.1.2 - 0.1.2) /Applications/MacDjView.app/Contents/MacOS/MacDjView
  0x6e1000 -   0x6e1ffb +cl_kernels (???) <B609BD37-C378-44DB-A15F-BBB1FB24E96A> cl_kernels
  0x6ee000 -   0x6eeff9 +cl_kernels (???) <721B579B-7AC4-4184-A4D4-AABDC0C5763F> cl_kernels
 0x4267000 -  0x4352ff7  unorm8_bgra.dylib (2.4.5) <A9015D26-FCF1-3BCD-A052-54912C2ED206> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ImageFormats/unorm8_bgra.dylib
0x8fe4f000 - 0x8fe82e03  dyld (353.2.1) <06B1254D-9BB9-327C-BA15-8F18FFF97586> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90008000 - 0x9010cff7  libJP2.dylib (1232) <CD0012B6-D649-327B-B7FA-E52B0FC0067C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
0x9010d000 - 0x90120fff  libcmph.dylib (1) <2449B048-208E-36FB-9DFA-47E0F3BCF132> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x90121000 - 0x90217ff7  libxml2.2.dylib (26) <2F37833C-4D55-3A09-9A0C-5904E8B6892A> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x90218000 - 0x9021cffb  libGIF.dylib (1232) <037E01F1-885C-3F4A-A353-87DB1F9CB504> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
0x904bb000 - 0x90555fff  com.apple.ColorSync (4.9.0 - 4.9.0) <091CDCEC-1B25-3FE7-94C2-8AEFA6564E95> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x90556000 - 0x90558ff3  com.apple.EFILogin (2.0 - 2) <CA5B7995-F183-31F3-B918-27965B2BDE8F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EFILogin.framework/Versions/A/EFILogin
0x90559000 - 0x905f6fff  com.apple.ink.framework (10.9 - 213) <F47949BC-ABEE-329B-B568-71C6FEF761F6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
0x905f7000 - 0x90612ff7  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.10 - 187) <5302DBFA-92CE-349C-981C-2BF6E9BEEBB0>
```

I have already checked this answer and according to AdwareMedic, my computer has no Adware affecting it: [Safari dosen't open anymore "reopen"](https://superuser.com/questions/855762/safari-dosent-open-anymore-reopen)

I have also tried uninstalling MacDjVu by removing it from the Applications folder, but re-installing it did not solve the issue. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you ever run MacDjView successfully under OS X 10.10.2? Under any version of Yosemite? It's a very old application that's had no updates for nearly a decade, and it may simply not work under Yosemite -- Apple improves stability by not being as careful about backwards software compatibility as Microsoft.

Comment: Yep, it worked (run successfully) three days ago.